# Вопрос по jQuery (манипулирование HTML элементами)

Tags: jquery, html

Есть два блока div - в одном textarea, а в другом диве хочу выводить - 500 символов осталось и чтобы число динамически уменьшалось при вводе текста в textarea.

```
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div>
500 символов осталось
</div>
```

Подскажите, как это реализовать проще всего с помощью jQuery?

Также интересует как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Оставить комментарий" появлялись плавно два дива, про которые речь шла выше? Всем заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Спасибо, всем кто помог решить проблему!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код на нативе:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
<title>Счётчик</title>
<script>
    var maxLength = 500; // Максимум символов
    window.onload = function(){
        txt_area = document.getElementById("txt_area");
        counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        counter.innerHTML = maxLength + " символов осталось";
    };
    function changeCount(obj){
        var val = txt_area.value;
        counter.innerHTML = maxLength - val.length + " символов осталось";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txt_area" onkeyup="changeCount(this)" onchange="changeCount(this)"></textarea>
<div id="counter"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: избыток глобальных переменных

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    <textarea maxlength="500" id="t"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="i">
    500 символов осталось
</div>

<script>
    $('#t').keyup(function(){
        $('#i').html((500-$('#t').val().length)+' символов осталось')    
    })

</script>
```

Появление этих полей — смотря как нужно. самый простой вариант:

```
<input type="button" value="Оставить комментарий" id="b"/>
<div id="c">
    <div>
        <textarea id="t"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="i">
        500 символов осталось
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#c').hide();
    $('#b').click(function(){
        $('#c').show(500); //500 — скорость анимации в миллисекундах
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает. Он ломается здесь:

       $('#i').html((500-$('#t').val.length)+' символов осталось')

Comment: @Asen а поправить не?

Comment: @Asen, исправил ведь сразу же

Answer (score 1):

Вам было бы достаточно одной строчки jQuery, к примеру:

```
<textarea onkeydown="func(this)" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>
...
<div id = "count">500</div>
...
<script>
function func(obj)
{
    $("#count").text(500-($(obj).val().length));
    }
</script>
...
```

И после того, как пользователь нажмет на кнопочку, которая записывает введенный текст куда-то в базу данных, не забудьте еще раз проверить, что в полученном тексте 500 символов и не более. А вдруг пользователь **изменил содержимое textarea через исходный код**!?

Comment: проверяйте еще раз. keydown срабатывает на нажатие клавиши. после того как клавишу отпустят может быть сильно больше символов, чем при срабатывании вашего кода. по крайней мере на 1 символ разница будет почти наверное.

Comment: А хотя нет! Ошибок-то нет.  Сами проверьте. В одну строку textarea помещается 62 символа. Вот и получается, что никакого промаха нет)

onMouseDown на то и онмаусдаун, что отлавливает каждое нажатие( в том числе и зажимание ) кнопки клавиатуры. Так что, думаю, это вы ошиблись...

Comment: для клавиатуры нужно два обработчика на keypress и keyup. keydown тут не годится. плюс можно еще мышью вставить или вырезать текст, тоже не сработает.

Comment: ИМХО достаточно keydown и динамического таймаута

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, это, скорее, уже вопрос надежности. Я за надежность. Но мой код тоже работает без промахов. Я проверил) 

---
Ведь можно было бы просто JS-таймер поставить с интервалом в 0.01 сек и проверять количество символов, но и таймер можно убрать через исходный код...

Comment: @Asen не буду с вами спорить. Вот вам [пример][1], тестируйте.

@AlexWindHope, с динамическим таймаутом - игра в поиск оптимального соотношения интервала иначе тормозить будет или редко совпадать. Но, да вариант наиболее точный.

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/cCUEC/